# How do I write this jQuery code in Postman?

Tags: jquery, api, postman

I'm starting to learn about API's and integration. So far I've had no issues with requesting using an URL. However, the other day I came across some API documentation, which had the following jQuery example:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://my.delogue.com/auth/token",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": "yourusername",
        "password": "yourpassword"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        token = data.access_token;
    },
    error: function(x, y, z) {
        alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
    }
});
```

How do I write this in the Postman software? More specifically, what part is the header, parameter, etc? I'm trying to understand the "anatomy" of the request, and even though this might not be the best place to start, I'd like to give it a shot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe you can add code like jQuery in postman

Comment: `data` contains the parameters (but since it's a POST they will be sent in the body, not as querystring parameters). And since the content-type is JSON, you'll need to add them as a JSON object in PostMan, not as individual parameters. `contentType` will set the content-type header. `crossDomain` doesn't apply to non-ajax requests. `dataType` is irrelevant because that's just about how jQuery deals with the response. `url` and `type` are easy to set in Postman. If you read the jquery docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ you can see what all those options do.

Comment: Use fiddler to capture your request.. you can then reproduce them in postman if you wish

Comment: Postman can be used to capture requests made my chrome. You could perhaps take a look at the [documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests/).

Comment: There are no headers in that request. The URL and type are self explanatory. To add the JSON to the body, change the content format to 'raw' and the type to 'JSON (application/json)', then paste in what you have. It should look something like this: https://i.imgur.com/e32zz13.png

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There is a header: `contentType` sets the content-type header, I believe.

Comment: That true, what I more accurately should have said is that no additional headers are needed in Postman. By setting 'application/json' in the body type that header will be automatically added for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So, I added the parameters to the body as raw and type application/json. But when I send the request I get `{"error": "unsupported_grant_type"}` (bad request) when I use the url `https://my.delogue.com/auth/token` and if I use `https://my.delogue.com/auth/token/` it returns html code.

Comment: That error means that you need to add whatever authentication details are necessary to the request. You've not specified what they are in the question, but it shouldn't be too hard. Find the necessary credentials/token and add them where needed - usually as a header

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Documentation says: `While calling these API you to provide user credentials using post method as shown in below example` (and then the code example I've posted in the question is shown). But the credentials are written in the body, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So, actually ended up changing the body from `raw` to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and passing the `grant_type`, `username`, `password` as key-value pairs, which worked :)

Comment: evidently the API can accept either JSON or url-encoded values, then. That's not uncommon. ASP.NET Web API can do that by default, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up doing the following:

- Set url as `https://my.delogue.com/auth/token`
- Under body in Postman, I chose `x-www-form-urlencoded`, as passed the following values (where values for `username` and `password` were replaced with my credentials):
  [image]

Apparently that did the trick for me.